# Flutter: How to loop through each field in `DocumentSnapshot.data()`

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection where each user has their own document. In the document I create a map for a new entry. The document would look something like this:
[image: Sample Document]

In my app, I want to get the document and then turn it into a list where each map (titled by the time) would be an entry. I tried looping through it but the problem is that there is not a forEach() in the `DocumentSnapshot.data()` and it is a type of `_JsonDocumentSnapshot`.

How can I get this as a List where `2021-05-30 20:49:59.671705`, `2021-05-30 20:50:00:600294`, ... are individual elements in a list. I plan on building each entry on its own using something such as a `ListView.builder()` so I would like to have a list of all those entries.

Edit:
My code looks something like this:

`journal` is just a `DocumentReference`.

```
journal.snapshots().forEach((element) {
      var data = element.data();
      print(element.data());

      (data ?? {}).forEach((key, value) {
        return JournalEntryData(
            date: key,
            entryText: value['entryText'],
            feeling: value['feeling']);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the type of `data` which was set to `element.data()` was `Object?` hence the `forEach()` method wasn't defined. I tried casting the `element.data()` as a `List` which caused errors so I didn't go further down that path. What I should have done was to cast `element.data()` as a `Map` which worked. I also should have used `journal.get()` and not `snapshots()` as it is a stream so the `await` keyword would result in the `journal.snapshots().forEach()` to never end.

The final code looked something like this:

```dart
Future<List<JournalEntryData>> getJournalEntries() async {
  List<JournalEntryData> entries = [];

  await journal.get().then((document) {
    Map data = (document.data() as Map);
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      print('adding entry');
      entries.add(JournalEntryData(
        date: key,
        entryText: value['entryText'],
        feeling: value['feeling'],
      ));
    });
  });

  return entries;
}
```

and I would do the following to get the entries:

```dart
var entries = await getJournalEntries();
```

Comment: A slightly better way would be to cast on the variable declaration like this: await journal.get().then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> document) {

Answer (score 0):

Hey for most of my problems like these I choose to go with this approach;

```
final result = await _db
          .collection("collectionName")
          .get();

      List<Object> toReturn = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < result.docs.length; i++) {
       // add data to list you want to return.
        toReturn.add();
          }
```

Hopefully, this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. The problem is that each document is private to a user. So I do not want to get the entire collection but rather just a specific document and deal with that data to reduce the amount of data needed to be fetched and for security reasons. The problem is that if I have a `DocumentSnapshot` and I use the `.data()` it returns an object so I can't do anything with it other than print it which returns something which looks like this `{{...}, {...}, ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List collectionElements = [];

void messagesStream() async {
  await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('your collection').snapshots().where(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .every((element) => element.author == currentUser.id),
        )) {
    collectionElements.add(snapshot);
  }
  print(collectionElements);
}
```

Each element would be added to the collectionElements list.

If you want to access only one field in your snapshot this works fine:

```
final entryText= element.data()['entryText'];
print(entryText); // this would print "lorem ipsum..."
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not want to get the entire collection but rather just a specific document and deal with that data to reduce the amount of data needed to be fetched and for security reasons. The problem I have is that I have a collection and can't deal with the `.data()` and do anything other than print it. It returns something like `{{...}, {...}, ...}`. I have edited my post with my code.

Comment: i see, would it be a problem if you add a field to the documents containing the author's id so when you call for the snapshots you can just do something like 
if (document.author == currentUser.id)
{
add stuf to the list
}

Comment: I have a collection called 'journal' and in the collection I would make a new document with the user's `uid`. So I can get the document and I infact do and can print the fields to the console when I print `element.data()` as seen in the code. The problem comes when I want to loop through the data as seen in the rest of the function. What is the type of element.data()? That is my only problem, it has a type of Object so I want to cast it, the problem is when I cast it as a list (`element.data() as List`) it throws an error.

Comment: or do you mean the document.author == currentUser.id in the security rules?

Comment: i edited my answer, i cant text what collectionElements print right now, but im guessing this filters out the documents you dont want and add those you do want to the list.
Can you text and tell me what printing that list gives you?
and i did not meant to add that to the security rules.

Comment: Hello Jamie, thanks for the help. I'm quite new to stackoverflow so I'm not sure what you mean by texting you.

Comment: Im sorry, that was an error, i meant "test"

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem turned out to be a casting issue. I just had to cast `DocumentSnapshot.data()` as a `Map` and that solved the problem.