# Flutter - String, dynamic is not a subtype of type List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter

I'm try to load data from rest api to my app get bellow error:

On emulator get this error:

```
type '_internalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

source:

```
Future <List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  final response =  await http.get(Uri.https('json-generator.com', 'api/json/get/cqwVqdOFrC?indent=2'));


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.map((data) => new Data.fromJson(data)).toList();

  } else {
    throw Exception('Error!');
  }
}

class Data {
  final int empno;
  final String ename;
  final int sal;

  Data({this.empno, this.ename, this.sal});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      empno: json['empno'],
      ename: json['ename'],
      sal: json['sal']
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as follows.

```
Future <List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  final response =  await http.get(Uri.https('json-generator.com', 'api/json/get/cqwVqdOFrC?indent=2'));

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse =json.decode(response.body);
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemsList =
      List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonResponse["items"]);
         return itemsList.map<Data>((data) {
           return Data.fromJson(data);
           }).toList();

  } else {
    throw Exception('Error!');
  }
}

class Data {
  final int empno;
  final String ename;
  final int sal;

  Data({this.empno, this.ename, this.sal});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      empno: json['empno'],
      ename: json['ename'],
      sal: json['sal']
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for help after use your code get this error:   https://ibb.co/60kJP2J

Comment: Can you show the response you are getting from the http request

Comment: Response here:   ibb.co/fDCQdRN

Comment: I have edited the answer this was because we had to map the `items` not the entire response body.

Comment: I'm try code but get:   type 'List<dynamic>' is noz a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Data>>'  on emulator

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently with Firestore. What I did in my case is I casted the result from my call as a map. This is the issue I opened: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67774067/15782390.

For your code, could you try this for your `fetchData()` method:

```
Future <List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  List<Data> data = [];
  final response =  await http.get(Uri.https('json-generator.com', 'api/json/get/cqwVqdOFrC?indent=2'));


  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    (response as Map).forEach((element) {
    // I'm not sure what information the data class contains but if you know the parameters that it takes in then add them here. If not then please share your data class.
     data.add(Data(/*enter your data class parameters here*/))
    });
    return data
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error!');
  }
}
```

I haven't tried the code out myself so if it doesn't work and you are unable to fix it maybe have a look at the question I linked. If that doesn't work either then let me know and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: Tnx for help, but if you can put all code instead comment at the line 5 (continue the code here where you `map` it)

Comment: @user_odoo I have updated my code. I'm not quite suer what your data class is so I left that blank but other than that everything else should work as soon as you copy paste it in.